# VS Code Python extension v2023.18.0 stopped resolving all python imports and Sort Imports option not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My VS Code was working fine, I have a pyenv environment with a specific python version and installed dependencies which I was using and all was good and suddenly it stopped recognizing all imports. [They are all whited out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITTOR.png).

Also I noticed that [the Sort Imports option disappeared from the context menu options I have when I right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1ko.png).

I have not changed anything in VS Code, any idea what might be wrong? Current VS Code Python extension version `2023.18.0`

Comment: @matszwecja i dont think this falls under these guidelines, they dont say to not post images in general they say to not post images of code, please re-read that topic. Posting images of non-code issues is essential.

Comment: Obviously something changed. You installed/uninstalled/edited/updated/configured something on your computer.

Comment: No I dint change anything on my side, but aftyer digging around a lot I Found out VSCode stopped support for isort so you cant acces it on the context menu. Also going back to a previous version of VSCode solved the import resolution thing. I ll post an answer below since both of these things are very fresh changes from VSCode side and many people will probably struggle to find what happened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These seem to be fresh issues coming from VSCode and Python extension for VSCode.

After doing a lot of digging around I think both of these issues come from very recent changes from VSCode. I mean they were just released this month (October 2023).

So regarding the `Sort Imports` option VSCode just stopped supporting it this month, see reference and ticket opened on [VSCode github here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22147)

To be able to still get automatic sorting of our imports we need to explicitly install the `isort` extension in VSCode and Use the Organize Imports command with sortkey `Shift` + `Alt` + `O`.

If someone wants to automate it completely you can add automatic import sorting on saving. Go to `Preferences` (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`) search for `Open User Settings (JSON)`. In the json file add this or modify the `"[python]"` settings section if already exists:

```
 "[python]": {
    ...Other settings...
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    },
  },
```

Now if you restart VSCode you should get automated sorting of imports on save. Also see some [visual instructions here](https://eshlox.net/2019/12/02/vscode-sort-python-imports-automatically).

Regarding the issue of imports not being recognized I downgraded the VSCode Python extension to a previous version `2023.2.0` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As for the import sorting not being in the command palette or context menu anymore, see [the notes for the v2023.18.0 release (September 2023)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/v2023.18.0), which state:

> - Remove sort imports from command palette and context menu by @ludizhan in [#22058](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/22058)

If you read the Pull Request, it is for [Drop the "Sort Imports" menu option #20233](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20233), where the rationale is that the context menu item and command palette command are redundant when there is a Code Actions menu item.

The maintainers also got feedback that many users of the Python extension don't use isort, so they're removing isort support in the October 2023 release of the Python extension: [Remove isort support #22187](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/22187) (see also [Sort Imports not working
#22147](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22147)). See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions.

Apparently you can instead use the conventional `Organize Imports` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) instead, which is bound by default to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt/opt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Sort imports has been removed from the command palette and context menu (see answers by @KZiovas and @starball). You can make changes to your JSON settings file to enable organizing your imports when saving your code.

Using the old SortImports:

```
"[python]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sortImports": true
  },
}
```

Using OrganizeImports (removes unused imports and organizes them):

```
"[python]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.organizeImports.reorder-python-imports": true
  },
}
```

Using OrganizeImports (not using isort but sorting imports):

```
"[python]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false,
    "source.organizeImports.reorder-python-imports": true
  },
}
```

Comment: so... you're not going to mention the extension that you need to install to use your answer?